# Why does ‘Geh mal schnell’ have no ‘e’ in this example?

Tags: idiomaticity

The Goethe Institut A1 wordlist has, as the example of usage for *die Bäckerei*, the following sentence:

> Ich geh mal schnell zur Bäckerei.

Why *geh*, or is the whole sentence merely a rendition of colloquial speech?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence is colloquial speech, but *geh* (or *geh’* with an *Auslassungszeichen*) is nothing more than a shortened version of *gehe*. So, in a bit more formal tone the sentence would be

> Ich gehe mal schnell zur Bäckerei.